# Iterate over JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, foreach

I have a JSON file containing a list of universities around the world. I want to get only specific universities where a field in the array matches what I need to select. The problem I face is that each university has it's own ID number which makes me unable to figure out how to iterate over the Array. The JSON file can be found on this [GitHub](https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list/blob/master/world_universities_and_domains.json) repo.

The code that makes me convert the JSON file to an array:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('universities_list.json');
    $universityArray = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($universityArray);
?>
```

And a sample of what I get is:

```
[2942] => Array
        (
            [alpha_two_code] => EG
            [country] => Egypt
            [domain] => aast.edu
            [name] => Arab Academy for Science & Technology
            [web_page] => http://www.aast.edu/
        )

    [2943] => Array
        (
            [alpha_two_code] => EG
            [country] => Egypt
            [domain] => akhbaracademy.edu.eg
            [name] => Akhbar El Yom Academy
            [web_page] => http://www.akhbaracademy.edu.eg/
        )
```

What is the best or appropriate way to print out only the universities with `alpha_two_code == 'EG'` or `== 'Egypt'` for example?

I read the documentation on [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and the examples as well. But still can't get the logic to get what I mentioned above.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the manual.

Try this:

```
$names = array();
foreach($universityArray as $u) {
  if($u['alpha_two_code'] == 'EG' || $u['country'] == 'Egypt'){
    $names[] = $u['name'];
  }
}

print_r($names);
```

Comment: Your code prints only one university

Comment: it's fixed now. try now.

Answer (score 2):

Check this return only a specific country

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents('university.json');
        $universityArray = json_decode($json, true);
        universities= array()
        for($i=0; $i< count($universityArray); $i++)
        {  
            if($universityArray[$i]["country"] == "Morocco")
             universitises[] = $universityArray[$i];
        }
        var_dump($universitises);
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alpha_two_code` as index.

```
$indexed = [];
foreach($universityArray as $university){
    $index = $university['alpha_two_code'];
    if(!isset($indexed[$index])){
        $indexed[$index] = [];
    }
    $indexed[$index][] = $university;
}
```

Now you will have universities seperated by `alpha_two_code` which you can directly access.

```
print_r($indexed['EG']);
```

Now as per the best and appropriate part, you may want to cache `$indexed`. You can create a directory for universities and save JSON encoded `$indexed` there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `array_filter` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php function here with a callback.  You can then use `array_column` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.phpto grab just the 'name' column.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list/blob/master/world_universities_and_domains.json');
$universityArray = json_decode($json, true);

$filterBy = 'EG';

$newArray = array_filter($universityArray, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return ($var['alpha_two_code'] == $filterBy);
});

print_r($newArray);

$names = array_column($newArray, 'name');

print_r($names);
```

Comment: How can I print only the names of universities?

Comment: @Tes3awy I have updated my example for you